# HTML Scrolling to Div Menu

Tags: javascript, html

```
<a href="#1">some text</a>    
<div id="1"></div>
```

I know how to make the simple clickable text to scroll the page.
But i want this menu like there 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/trXZn.png
I want it to move with screen and look good. the circles are fine!
The popup on mouse enter looks good and animates good.
**Anyway the scrolling works** So i need only the bar. I will appreciate if you make one for me or if you send me a link of one already made.
I dont know the HTML or JS.

EDIT--
So I just want How it calls. How to make it. Or give me some example.

So its just the circles on the right side of page moving up and down how people scroll the page, and when i click it i want to redict to the page with /#div

Comment: Can you provide some code to what you've tried to do?

Comment: your question is not clear, please add more info to it. if possible with more images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple one I made in 20 minutes or so. That should be a good start for you.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var menuItems = document.querySelectorAll(".menu_item");

  for(var i=0; i<menuItems.length; i++) {
    menuItems[i].onclick = function(event) {
      var ref = event.target.getAttribute("data-ref");
      
      document.querySelector(ref).scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth', block: 'start'});
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#menu {
  right: 5px;
  position: fixed;

  bottom: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(50%);
  -moz-transform: translateY(50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(50%);
  -o-transform: translateY(50%);
  transform: translateY(50%);
}

.menu_item {
  position: relative;

  background: #999999;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.menu_item:hover {
  background: #5896ca;
}

.menu_label {
    position: absolute;
    right: 24px;
    transform: translateX(0%);
    background: #5896ca;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 109px;
    display: none;
    color: white;
}

.menu_item:hover .menu_label {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
  <div class="menu_item" data-ref="#home">
    <div class="menu_label">Home</div>
   </div>
   <div class="menu_item" data-ref="#about">
    <div class="menu_label">About</div>
   </div>
   <div class="menu_item" data-ref="#contact">
    <div class="menu_label">Contact Us</div>
   </div>
   <div class="menu_item" data-ref="#something_else">
    <div class="menu_label">Something Else</div>
   </div>
</div>

<h2 id="home">HOME</h2>

<p>home content</p>
<p>home content</p>
<p>home content</p>
<p>home content</p>
<p>home content</p>
<p>home content</p>
<p>home content</p>
<p>home content</p>
<p>home content</p>
<p>home content</p>
<p>home content</p>
<p>home content</p>
<p>home content</p>

<h2 id="about">ABOUT US</h2>

<p>about us content</p>
<p>about us content</p>
<p>about us content</p>
<p>about us content</p>
<p>about us content</p>
<p>about us content</p>
<p>about us content</p>
<p>about us content</p>
<p>about us content</p>
<p>about us content</p>
<p>about us content</p>
<p>about us content</p>
<p>about us content</p>
<p>about us content</p>
<p>about us content</p>

<h2 id="contact">CONTACT US</h2>

<p>contact us content</p>
<p>contact us content</p>
<p>contact us content</p>
<p>contact us content</p>
<p>contact us content</p>
<p>contact us content</p>
<p>contact us content</p>
<p>contact us content</p>
<p>contact us content</p>
<p>contact us content</p>
<p>contact us content</p>
<p>contact us content</p>
<p>contact us content</p>
<p>contact us content</p>

<h2 id="something_else">SOMETHING ELSE</h2>

<p>something else content</p>
<p>something else content</p>
<p>something else content</p>
<p>something else content</p>
<p>something else content</p>
<p>something else content</p>
<p>something else content</p>
<p>something else content</p>
<p>something else content</p>
<p>something else content</p>
<p>something else content</p>
<p>something else content</p>
<p>something else content</p>
<p>something else content</p>
<p>something else content</p>
<p>something else content</p>
```

Comment: It looks good, But it doesnt work, when i click on it, nothing happens :/

Comment: @TomiKordos are you clicking on the circles? It works for me.

Comment: Yeah, but i dont know what tag to use in the first code.. the <script> or code or style havent work

Comment: Are you familiar with javascript? If not you need to learn it asap if you are going to become a serious web developer. I have changed the answer to a purely javascript answer (removed the jquery dependence). Try it out

Comment: I still dont know if i have put the code in <script> or <code> becouse it doesnt work... :/

Comment: Please? Or its any other way? Please tell :/

Answer (score 1):

You could probably do something similar to this:

```css
#menu {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

#menu a {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: lightblue;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 50px;
  margin: 10px;
  transition-duration: 1s;
}

#menu a:hover {
  background: blue;
}

p {
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
  <a href="#1"></a>
  <a href="#2"></a>
  <a href="#3"></a>
  <a href="#4"></a>
  <a href="#5"></a>
 </div>
<div id="content">
  <p id="1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Condimentum lacinia quis vel eros donec ac odio. Velit dignissim sodales ut eu sem integer vitae justo eget. Ac placerat vestibulum lectus mauris ultrices eros in cursus. Nunc congue nisi vitae suscipit. Venenatis cras sed felis eget velit aliquet sagittis id. Quis ipsum suspendisse ultrices gravida dictum fusce ut placerat. Vitae tempus quam pellentesque nec nam aliquam. Adipiscing enim eu turpis egestas pretium aenean. Convallis tellus id interdum velit laoreet id donec ultrices. Gravida rutrum quisque non tellus orci ac auctor. Sed risus ultricies tristique nulla aliquet enim tortor at. Morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac.</p>

<p id="2">Tortor at risus viverra adipiscing at. Velit ut tortor pretium viverra suspendisse potenti nullam ac. Ut sem viverra aliquet eget sit amet tellus. Vel elit scelerisque mauris pellentesque pulvinar. Suscipit adipiscing bibendum est ultricies integer quis auctor. Vel risus commodo viverra maecenas accumsan. Odio euismod lacinia at quis risus. Adipiscing at in tellus integer feugiat scelerisque varius morbi enim. Elit at imperdiet dui accumsan sit amet. Consectetur purus ut faucibus pulvinar elementum integer. Nulla malesuada pellentesque elit eget gravida.</p>

<p id="3">Tortor pretium viverra suspendisse potenti nullam. Viverra vitae congue eu consequat ac. Nunc pulvinar sapien et ligula ullamcorper. Tellus at urna condimentum mattis. Volutpat odio facilisis mauris sit amet. Ut tristique et egestas quis ipsum. Leo integer malesuada nunc vel risus commodo viverra maecenas accumsan. Nisl nisi scelerisque eu ultrices. Sit amet luctus venenatis lectus magna fringilla urna porttitor rhoncus. Aliquam purus sit amet luctus venenatis lectus. Lectus sit amet est placerat in egestas. Sapien nec sagittis aliquam malesuada bibendum. Adipiscing tristique risus nec feugiat in fermentum posuere urna. Sem et tortor consequat id. Et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas sed tempus urna et. Etiam tempor orci eu lobortis elementum.</p>

<p id="4">Augue neque gravida in fermentum. Tellus mauris a diam maecenas sed enim ut. Molestie ac feugiat sed lectus vestibulum. Facilisi etiam dignissim diam quis enim lobortis. Sed euismod nisi porta lorem mollis aliquam ut. Quis commodo odio aenean sed adipiscing. Id donec ultrices tincidunt arcu non sodales. Sed egestas egestas fringilla phasellus faucibus scelerisque eleifend. Non tellus orci ac auctor augue mauris augue neque gravida. Sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes nascetur. Aenean euismod elementum nisi quis eleifend quam adipiscing. Nulla facilisi etiam dignissim diam quis enim lobortis. Blandit turpis cursus in hac habitasse platea dictumst quisque. Eget sit amet tellus cras adipiscing enim eu. Odio facilisis mauris sit amet. Quis viverra nibh cras pulvinar mattis nunc sed. Maecenas pharetra convallis posuere morbi leo urna molestie at.</p>

<p id="5">Praesent semper feugiat nibh sed pulvinar proin gravida hendrerit lectus. Mattis nunc sed blandit libero volutpat sed cras ornare. Purus sit amet volutpat consequat mauris nunc. Vitae ultricies leo integer malesuada nunc. Porttitor eget dolor morbi non. Ut pharetra sit amet aliquam. Mi sit amet mauris commodo. Vel orci porta non pulvinar. Proin sed libero enim sed faucibus. Eu lobortis elementum nibh tellus molestie nunc non. Fermentum leo vel orci porta. At tempor commodo ullamcorper a.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: This one works nice!, but it does the thing over my meno of pages: https://imgur.com/a/yGdaBRL

Comment: I mean "menu" not meno*